# joint probability and terminal position of stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Consider a standard Brownian motion which runs from time $t=0$ to time $t=4$. 
> $(a)$ give the expression for the probability that its path position is positive at time $4$. Give the numerical value of this probability 
> $(b)$ For the Brownian motion described above, give the expression for the joint probability that its path position is positive at time $1$ as well as positive at time $4$. 
> $(c)$ give the expression for the expected value at time $4$ of the position of the path described in (a).
> $(d)$ Verify that the terminal position of $X(t)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}B(t)-tB(1),\: t\in[0,1]$ equals to the initial position.

#### My approach

$(a)$ Density at $X=x$ is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{4}}e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-0}{\sqrt{4}}\right)^2}$$We need to find the probability, $\mathbb P(X\geq0)=\int_0^\infty f(x)\:dx=0.5$

$(b)$ If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then their joint probability density function is, $$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$
So we need to find an expression of path position at time $1$ and $4$ and make it independent by increment because the increment is independent.
$$f_{B_{t_1}B_{t_4}}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1}}e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x_1-0}{\sqrt{1}}\right)^2}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{4-1}}e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{\sqrt{4-1}}\right)^2}$$
Is it correct?

$(c)$ Isn't it should be $0$ because $\mathbb E[B_t]=0$.

$(d)$ I need help for this problem. Do I need to show $\mathbb E[X(1)]=X(0)?$ $$\mathbb E[X(1)]=\mathbb E[B(1)-B(1)]=0\stackrel{?}{=}X(0)$$

It will be a great help someone verify my solution and let me know if further improvement required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For (b): $B_1$ and $B_4$ are not independent. For (d), you need to show that $X(0) = X(1)$.

Comment: $(b)$ I guess my expression is $B_1$ and $B_{4-1}$. Could you help me to write the correct expression? $(d)$ Okay, $X(1)=0$, do I need to assume $X(0)=0?$ Because that wasn't mentioned on the question that's why I am confused @JoseAvilez

Comment: For (b) observe that $(B_1, B_4)$ is a Gaussian vector with mean zero and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, where $\Sigma_{1,2} = \min(1,4) = 1$. For (d), a standard Brownian motion has $B(0) = 0$.

Comment: Aha, I miss that part in (d). Thanks, @JoseAvilez. I am afraid that maybe I couldn't understand your comment on $(b)$. Because I yet not learn multidimensional stochastic process. It will be great help if you explain it or give me some more hints to complete the solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with the multivariate Gaussian distribution?

Comment: I can grasp it, but this is not included in this semester. @JoseAvilez